# Delete focus from toolbar item

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode4, nstoolbar

I have a toolbar with custom items. When i click on item, left item get a focus. How to delete focus from toolbar item?

[image]

Comment: When the "Full Keyboard Access" radio button "All controls" is cheked and i open Preferences window for other app the toolbar item haven't focus. I think that i have a problem in my own app

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have "Full Keyboard Access" set to "All controls".  You can press tab a few times until the focus goes away from the toolbar item.

If you want to disable the ability to focus on other objects other than text boxes and lists (so you can no longer focus on toolbar items and such), you can do that two ways:  1) press Control + F7, or 2) go to System Preferences, Keyboard preference pane, select the Keyboard Shortcuts tab, and change the "Full Keyboard Access" radio button from "All Controls" to "Text boxes and lists only".

Comment: Ok. This work, but when the "Full Keyboard Access" radio button "All controls" is cheked and i open Preferences window for other app the toolbar item haven't focus. I think that i have a problem in my own app...More ideas?

Comment: Hmmmm...  My initial gut reaction has to do with that NSToobarItem becoming first responder (which makes it become outlined in blue).  I was formulating another answer around this, but then I found out that NSToolbar and NSToolbarItem doesn't inherit from NSResponder or NSView.  When you say a "toolbar with custom items", do you mean that you have subclassed NSToolbarItem?  If so, you might add this method to your subclass: `-(BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder { return NO; }`

Comment: I haven't subclassed NSToolbarItem. I use Image Toolbar Item object and set own image...